# MySQL query help count please

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Alright I have the MYSQL query code setup to pull this information out of my database. What I would like to do now is count by code but group it by name.

```
$sql = "SELECT  m.* 
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code  
                  FROM Transaction) md 
          JOIN Transaction m ON m.ID_Transaction = (SELECT  ID_Transaction
                                                      FROM Transaction mi
                                                     WHERE mi.Code = md.Code 
                                                       AND Date_Time=CURdate() 
                                                       AND Time_Stamp!=''
                                                  ORDER BY m.Name DESC, mi.Code DESC, mi.Date_Time DESC, mi.ID_Transaction DESC
                                                     LIMIT 1)";
```

With my php code this is what i get from this query.

```
rick, 002455, 2010-11-10, 08:30 AM  
rick, 003819, 2010-11-10, 08:45 AM  
amber, 003572, 2010-11-10, 08:45 AM  
eric, 001479, 2010-11-10, 10:30 AM  
jerry, 001012, 2010-11-10, 09:45 AM
```

rick being name
000000 being code

I want to take this information and count it like so for each name.

```
rick = 2  
amber = 1  
eric = 1  
jerry = 1
```

I'm not sure how I would do this? Can I use the information in the query to make another query to count this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m.name, count(*) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Code
FROM Transaction
) md JOIN Transaction m ON
m.ID_Transaction = ( SELECT ID_Transaction FROM Transaction mi WHERE mi.Code = md.Code AND Date_Time=CURdate() AND Time_Stamp!='' ORDER BY m.Name DESC, mi.Code DESC, mi.Date_Time DESC, mi.ID_Transaction DESC LIMIT 1 )
 group by m.name
```